Экранирование символа-разделителя при использовании Regex.Split()
Мне нужно разделить строку используя разделитель #. Но в этой строке одна из частей может быть 16-ричным выражением цвета, например, #3ffdca. Пример строки: color##3ffdca#System.String.
Если я разделю её по #, то получится 4 части, при этом часть с цветом потеряет решётку. А мне нужно 3 части и чтобы часть с цветом сохранила решётку.
Какое регулярное выражение мне нужно написать в Regex, чтобы этого добиться?
Как вариант ещё думал ставить перед решёткой обратный слэш, чтобы помечать её как не разделитель.
Т.е. color#\#3ffdca#System.String
Но тогда тоже вопрос, что мне написать в Regex, чтобы оно разделило строку по #, но если перед # стоит \, то не воспринимало такую решётку, как разделитель?

К сожалению не могу так сделать. Если бы мог, то всё было гораздо проще.
А вообще, я уже нашёл то, что искал. Выражение (?<!\)# делает то, что мне нужно.

(?<!\\)#(?!.*(?<!\\)#[0-9a-fA-F]{6}) - по идее разделит строку input по #, сохраняя решётку перед 16-ричным выражением цвета и игнорируя случаи, когда перед решёткой стоит обратный слэш.

Ваше выражение можно упростить до (?<!\)# и оно будет делать то, что мне нужно.
Но спасибо.


Мне нужно разделить строку используя разделитель #. Но в этой строке одна из частей может быть 16-ричным выражением цвета, например, #3ffdca. Пример строки: color##3ffdca#System.String. Если я разделю её по #, то получится 4 части, при этом часть с цветом потеряет решётку. А мне нужно 3 части и чтобы часть с цветом сохранила решётку.

Такое делится без проблем... Пример на JavaScript


const s = 'color##3ffdca#System.String'
const r = /(?<!#)#/
console.log(s.split(r))



Но, если есть возможность повлиять на формирование строки - лучше выбрать уникальный символ для разделителя.

Это да, но могут быть ситуации, когда какая-то из частей строки - это пустая строка. Т.е. color##System.String. И в таком случае ваш вариант вернёт 2 строки. Но их всё также должно быть 3.
А вообще, я уже нашёл то, что искал. Выражение (?<!\)# делает то, что мне нужно.

@Zhizhka, для получения полноценного ответа нужно предоставлять больше информации сразу, а не по мере поступления ответов. ;)
